# Image padding beside text

Tags: css

I'm trying to allign two images on each side of the text using padding.

I works on the left side but not on the right.

Why will the right one dont fall down 10px?

html:

```
<img class="q1" src="http://i62.tinypic.com/2dkh7p2.png"/>
This is the quoted text, but how can I get the right img to align? Right now it's too high! --->
<img class="q2" src="http://i62.tinypic.com/282f3mr.png" />
```

css:

```
.q1 {
padding-right:2px;
padding-bottom:10px;
}
.q2 {
padding-left:2px;
margin-top:10px; 
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vvDdR/1/

Comment: You should wrap the text in a proper text tag...that will make it easier.

Comment: Is that what you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/vvDdR/7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using vertical margin or padding you can just nudge it:

```
.q2 {
    padding-left:2px;
    position:relative;
    top:10px; 
}
```

**Before:**

[image: Before]

**After**

[image: After]

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5g4wt/

Answer (score 2):

This should be made with background images in CSS.

As an example:

[Have a Fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/vvDdR/11/)

HTML

```
<blockquote>This is an amazing quote - mistermansam</blockquote>
```

[More information on semantic quotations in HTML5](http://html5doctor.com/blockquote-q-cite/).

CSS

```
blockquote {
    background: url(http://i62.tinypic.com/2dkh7p2.png) no-repeat;
    padding: 0 25px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 300px;
}
blockquote:after {
    content:'';
    background: url(http://i62.tinypic.com/282f3mr.png) no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    display: block;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

[image: Fiddle screenshot]

With a different typeface, this could also be achieved [without images](http://jsfiddle.net/vvDdR/12/).

Comment: Extra bonus props to this suggestion, because it uses semantic markup instead of adding extra images to the code

Comment: It's also very easy to maintain and re-use.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with `vertical-align`:

```
img {
    display:inline;    
}
.q1 {
    vertical-align:45%;
    margin-right:2px;
}
.q2 {
    vertical-align:-70%;
    margin-left:2px;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vvDdR/10/)

[MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align)

Answer (score 0):

Your current code won't work due to a simple typo.
The following does, given I understood your problem correctly.

[**Jsfiddle sample**](http://jsfiddle.net/vvDdR/6/)

```
.q1 {
    padding-right:2px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
}
.q2 {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: -10px;
}
```